# Why the same code in UI thread and work thread leads to different result?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a tricky issue.

1. There's a RecyclerView
2. Each child of RecyclerView have several programmatically generated Buttons:

`List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
for (int k = 0; k < values.length; k++) {
     String value = values[k];
     Button btnAnswer = (Button)LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate( R.layout.button_answer_unpressed, mainLayout, false);
     btnAnswer.setId(View.generateViewId());
     mainLayout.addView(btnAnswer);
     buttons.add(btnAnswer);
}
...
 for (Button button:buttons) {
     applyBlur(button, mainLayout);
 }`

3. The interesting part starts inside *applyBlur* method.

3.1. Realization **without** threads (I provide only a part of method which distinguishes in two realizations) :

```
private void applyBlur(final View view, final View parent) {
   ...
   parent.buildDrawingCache();
   final Bitmap bmp = parent.getDrawingCache();
   ...
   Bitmap blurredBitmap = blur(bmp, view);
   view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), blurredBitmap));
   ...
}
```

`view` variable is a Button passed as an argument. Function `blur` makes blur effect :) (taken from [here](http://trickyandroid.com/advanced-blurring-techniques/)) and it works fine. It looks as it have to (*see blur buttons*):
[image]

3.2. Realization **with** threads:

```
private void applyBlur(final View view, final View parent) {
    ...
    parent.buildDrawingCache();
    final Bitmap bmp = parent.getDrawingCache();
    ...
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                final Bitmap blurredBitmap = blur(bmp, view);
                                view.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), blurredBitmap));
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }).start();
   ...
}
```

You may notice that the code remains the same but just putted into Thread. However result is different:
[image]

I also tried `AsyncTask` and `AsyncTaskLoader` but result remains the same: only last Button gets blurred. If I keep everything in main thread - it's all right but not good for productivity.

I checked that `blurredBitmap` is always generated properly.

Why threads crash Button's background initialization?

Comment: your for loop is finishing before your first blur task is completed so only the last `view` is getting shown

Comment: @tyczj i see all the Views getting shown, but only the last is blurred

Comment: @pskink yeah because the last view is the one that is there when the first blur task finishes

Comment: @tyczj it is because all the tasks but the last complete before parent container calls onLayout, that's why. it has little to do with the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink, problem solved

```
mainLayout.post(new Runnable() { 
 @Override 
 public void run() { 
  for(Button btn:buttons) 
    applyBlur(btn, mainLayout); 
  } 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>(values.length);

for(int k = 0; k < values.length; k++) {
    buttons.add((Button) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.button_answer_unpressed, mainLayout, false););
}

for (int k = 0; k < buttons.size(); k++) {
String value = values[k];
buttons.get(k).setId(View.generateViewId());
mainLayout.addView(buttons.get(k));
applyBlur(buttons.get(k), mainLayout);
}
```

and have your applyBlur method use threads

Comment: I brought out `applyBlur` into separate loop and used `List` of `Buttons` but the result is same

Comment: @IlyaBlokh you have to start your tasks after parent's `onLayout` is called, see `ViewTreeObserver` class

Comment: @pskink I added `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to parent view `TreeObserver` but `onGlobalLayout` is never called (I added right after loop, `applyBlur` is inside `onGlobalLayout`)

Comment: @IlyaBlokh no after, add it before adding child views - before the loop

Comment: @pskink yes, already. However, result is same - only last button has new background.

Comment: @IlyaBlokh add some Log.d with blurredBitmap.getWidth() / getHeight() right after you call `final Bitmap blurredBitmap = blur(bmp, view);`

Comment: @pskink it is always positive (width = 72 to be exact). blur method works fine

Comment: and what about view.getLeft() / view.getTop()) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85131/discussion-between-ilya-blokh-and-pskink). @pskink

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work... When I get home from the office, I'll implement it myself and see what's going on. Let me know if you find a solution in the mean time